# GPUImage: EAGLContext and thread queue

Tags: ios, coding-style, opengl-es-2.0, gpuimage

Recently I'm improving my OpenGL ES skills looking into the source code of [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). While I was reading the code for the `GPUImageContext` class I get that it stores a reference to a `queue` that it's used in other parts of the library.

For example in `GPUImageView.m` the queue is used in `commonInit` with `runSynchronouslyOnVideoProcessingQueue` to perform some operations not directly related with the context (like adding attributes to the shader).

My question is why the developer has decided to perform these operations on a "secondary" queue and which is the benefit of storing this queue into a class like the `GPUImageContext`.

I know that question is strictly related with the GPUImage framework, but I think that it could be a big opportunity to understand how a skilled developer as Brad Larson has decided to structure one of the most famous library for Image Manipulation in iOS.

P.s. 
I hope I didn't offend the author with my curiosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is to provide a degree of thread safety. An OpenGL ES context can only be safely accessed from one thread at a time. To that end, I use a serial dispatch queue that I associate with the OpenGL ES context and dispatch anything that touches that context  on that queue.

The use of a serial dispatch queue is an efficient means of ensuring only one thing at a time touches a resource. It avoids the overhead from expensive locks, and makes it easy to perform processing operations on a non-main thread.

You could elect to do all this only on the main thread, which is what I did at first, but that had some disadvantages. Slow processing can block the UI. Doing OpenGL ES rendering on a background thread has significant performance advantages, ranging from a 10% speedup on even single-core devices, to an over 40% speedup on multicore iOS hardware. You're also protected against instances where a developer using the framework accesses it from a non-main thread.

Comment: Great! This is a really exhaustive answer.